# can a shared buffer be thread safe using std::atomic flags? is there a more efficient way to do it?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

**Hi SO!** Is there, by any change, a possibility that the "waiting thread" does not get the "buff" updated? should i put a lock_guard in the thread that changes the "buff"?
I've been reading about memory fences on some articles, like this one: https://bartoszmilewski.com/2008/11/05/who-ordered-memory-fences-on-an-x86/ and i am just worried about it.
Thanks in advance...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>

int main(){
    std::atomic<bool> ready(false);
    char buff[20]= "hello";

    std::cout << "creating thread to change \"buff\"..." << std::endl;
    std::thread tr(
        [ & ready, & buff ](){
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
            //should i put a lock_guard here?
            buff[0]= 'w'; buff[1]= 'o';
            buff[2]= 'r'; buff[3]= 'l';
            buff[4]= 'd'; buff[5]= '\0';
            std::cout << "buffer changed! sending signal to waiting thread..." << std::endl;
            ready= true;
    });

    tr.detach();
    std::cout << "...waiting for the change..." << std::endl;
    while(!ready);

    std::cout << "...got it! buff=" << buff << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by not calling `tr.join()` or `tr.detach()` before `tr` goes out of scope. Further, replacing the busy wait `while(!ready);` with `tr.join()` would have the same net effect, but be much more efficient.

Comment: thanks, you are right ... i've edited it and put the detach() now... i'm not interested in the join, i want the thread to run independently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't specify the memory visibility semantics for your assignment to `ready`, you get the default semantics. Which are:

> The default behavior of all atomic operations in the library provides for sequentially consistent ordering (see discussion below). -- [std::memory_order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)

So you get "sequentially consistent ordering". Well, what the heck is that?

> Any operation with this memory order is both an acquire operation and a release operation, plus a single total order exists in which all threads observe all modifications (see below) in the same order.

That sounds good. But what's a "release operation"?

> A store operation with this memory order performs the release operation: no memory accesses in the current thread can be reordered after this store. This ensures that all writes in the current thread are visible in other threads that acquire the same atomic variable and writes that carry a dependency into the atomic variable become visible in other threads that consume the same atomic.

So that means that any thread that sees the modification to `ready` will see any writes done before it, which includes the ones to `buff`. So this part of your code is fine as far as data races go. (It's horrible for lots of other reasons, of course.)

Comment: The most obvious is the `while(!ready);` which can compete for resources with the thread its waiting for. Imagine, for example, if the two threads are running in the same physical core on a hyper-threaded CPU. Also, what happens when that `while` loop finally breaks out? You will take the mother of all mispredicted branches. Of course, you're coding in a high level language, so you shouldn't really be too worried about exactly how or why it's bad. Just keep in mind that the language has ways to do these kinds of things correctly and *these are not them*. Atomics are not for waiting.

Comment: thank you, but what other solution for the waiting thread can i do if i call detach(); before the while(!ready); ? i'm sorry, i'm just new to multi-threading in c++11.

Comment: @enger Learn how to use [condition variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)s. You shouldn't be messing with atomics and memory visibility until you know how to use the normal stuff thoroughly and when you use something weird like this, you should know exactly why you've made that choice.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the recommendations of [David Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721269/david-schwartz) and [Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik), i changed the code to use condition variables and to detach the thread:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>

int main(){
    std::mutex mutex_condition;
    std::condition_variable condition;
    bool ready= false;
    char buff[20]= "hello";

    std::cout << "creating thread to change \"buff\"..." << std::endl;
    std::thread tr(
        [ & condition, & mutex_condition, & ready, & buff ](){
            {
              std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_(mutex_condition);
              std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
              buff[0]= 'w'; buff[1]= 'o';
              buff[2]= 'r'; buff[3]= 'l';
              buff[4]= 'd'; buff[5]= '\0';
              std::cout << "buffer changed! sending signal to waiting thread..." << std::endl;
              ready= true;
            }
            condition.notify_one();
    });

    std::cout << "...calling detach..." << std::endl;
    tr.detach();

    std::cout << "...waiting for the change..." << std::endl;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock_(mutex_condition);
    condition.wait(lock_, [ & ready ]{ return ready; });

    std::cout << "...got it! buff=" << buff << std::endl;
}
```

Thank you! Hopefully this could help somebody else.